# Linearizing non-linear least squares: Problem with derivatives

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, least-squares

We want to approximate $$y_i \approx a b^{x_i}$$
and thus have
$$S=\sum_{i=1}^m (ab^{x_i}-y_i)^2$$ as least squares error term. 
This term is not linear in b, so it is not easy to calculate its derivatives.

So, there is another method that approximates the relative error and thus approximates
$$\log y_i \approx \log a + x_i \log b$$ 
resulting in $$\tilde{S}=\sum_{i=1}^m (\log a +x_i\log b-\log y_i)^2$$
which is linear in $\log a$ and $\log b$ now.

I am now not sure how to solve the following:
I now would like to find $a$, $b$ such that the above $\tilde{S}$ is minimized.

Do I now have to set $$\frac{\delta \tilde{S}}{\delta \log a} =0$$ or
$$\frac{\delta \tilde{S}}{\delta a} =0$$ or is this the same?
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: It is (roughly) the same. By the chain-rule $dS/d\log a = a dS/da$ so unless $a=0$ they are equivalent. btw it should be $\log y_i$ (not $y_i$) in $\tilde{S}$: you also have to take the logs of the data-points.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for!! 
I've already changed $\log y_i$-part.

Comment: A final note: For simplicity I would call, for example, $\log a = \tilde{a}$ and similar for $b$ and then fit for $\tilde{a},\tilde{b}$ instead (to avoid carrying the log around).

Comment: Would you mind to either give me a link where the chain rule in this form is explained or to explain it. 
Because I know the simple rules of derivation, but if the variable is a function, I am a Little bit confused. I looked at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule but I am not sure which is the one I'm looking for.

Comment: What you are looking for is on that page, see the 3'rd equation: $\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$ which in your case becomes ($z = S$, $x=\log a$, $y=a$): $\frac{dS}{d\log a} = \frac{dS}{da}\frac{da}{d\log a}$ and we also have $\frac{da}{d\log a} = \frac{de^{\log a}}{d\log a} = e^{\log a} = a$ which gives the result.

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped a lot!